# add discount coupon code in newsletter subscription

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

How to add a **unique coupon code** for **newsletter subscriber**. I am beginner in magento so please help how to send subscription email with this coupon code. please help.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Manual solution**:

1. Create a coupon with your desired rules
2. Set the number of uses to **1** per customer and unlimited for **general** usage.
3. Copy the coupon code in the newsletter email

**Path**: `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/locale/language_ISO/template/email/newsletter_subscr_confirm.html` for exemple.

2) **The dynamic one**:

Create an observer on the `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` or `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` that checks if the customer subscribes and if so, it creates a coupon with your desired settings. [See this for creating coupons by code](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html).
Then rewrite the method `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::sendConfirmationSuccessEmail` so you can pass that code as a parameter to the e-mail template.
Something like this:

```
$email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this, 'coupon_code'=>THE COUPON GENERATED IN THE EVENT)
    );
```

Then modify the newsletter subscription e-mail template to include this:

```
Your coupon code is: {{var coupon_code}}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283807/6408849).